# Notepad++ Macros

Tags: macros, notepad++

Is there a way to edit the test I have in a Macro?  ex.
I want to put the following text in a Macro for a cookbook Recipe:

- Exported from MasterCook *

{Recipe Name}

Recipe by   : {^v post name copied from clipboard}
Serving Size:       Preparation Time:0:00
Categories  : Breads, Rolls and Biscuits

Amount Measure        Ingredient -- Preparations

---

I can setup the macro to do this, but when the Category changes, I don't want to have to retype all of it, can I change the Categories to something else without retyping?

Thanks
Andy

Comment: See [macros](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#macros) within the Notepad++ manual page on configuration files. Read carefully the words about [editing](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#editing-configuration-files) configuration files.